# How do I access the backup of my iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, backup, windows

I backed up my iPod Touch (4th gen) a few months ago on iTunes. My iPod has subsequently died and I want to get at the photos and videos from the backup. But I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Where are they stored, and how do I get access to them?

iPod Touch 4th gen, iTunes on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7, the backup file is located here:
`C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

If you are on Windows XP, I'm sorry, and your backup file is located here:
`C:\Documents and Settings\[yourusername]\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

The backup file is a database file. You won't be able to browse it manually. You can either restore it to another iOS device, or you can use specialized software to extract the data for you. This is but one example of software that does this: http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com